# Difference between these two JavaScript Object declarations

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can anyone tell me what the difference is between doing this:

```
$scope.pageModel = {};
$scope.pageModel.varA = false;
$scope.pageModel.varB = ""; 
$scope.pageModel.varC = "";
```

and doing this:

```
$scope.pageModel = {
     varA = false,
     varB = "",
     varC = ""
};
```

If I do the second version my application breaks but if I go by the first it doesn't. Surely its just two ways of declaring the same values for the model? - Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Yes, the second one is not valid syntax.

Comment: Syntax correction aside, they both do the same thing.

Comment: good to know - new to javascript. Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$scope.pageModel = {
     varA: false,
     varB: "",
     varC: ""
};
```

(This is basic Javascript syntax, not really related to Angular at all)

Comment: thanks for the reply and noted - still new to javascript so forgive my ignorance!

Answer (score 1):

To make your second example work you need to define it as object not using =

```
app.controller('testCtr',
function testCtr($scope){
    $scope.pageModel = {
        varA : false,
        varB : "",
        varC : ""
        };
});
```

this will now work.
This are however fundamentals and I would recomend to read more about oop in javascript
some example is here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript
- http://www.objectplayground.com/

Answer (score 1):

### 2 things:

#### 1. Colon is used to map values to keys when using the *Object Literal* syntax:

```
var person = {
    name: "Tarzan"
};
```

#### 2. You can't reference an object during initialization when using object literal syntax. You need to reference the object after it is created:

This is invalid:

```
var items = {
    item1: 10,
    item2: items.item1 + 10 // invalid
};
```

While this is valid:

```
var items = {};
items.item1 = 10;
items.item2 = items.item1 + 10; // valid
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript object notation is

```
{
   attribute_1: value_1,
   attribute_2: value_2,
   .
   .
   .
   attribute_n: value_n
}
```

So you would need to declare your pageModel as follows:

```
$scope.pageModel = {
  varA: false,
  varB: "",
  varC: ""
};
```

Also, it's generally considered good style to declare your objects using object notation rather than declaring an empty object and then assigning to its attributes.